# JS manipulation over BEM CSS structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, bem

I'm getting  a hard time getting this:
BEM structure says I should do something like this:

```
.header
   .header__nav
      .header__icon
         .header__icon-text
      .header__menu
         .header__menu-list
```

But what if I want to toggle some CSS class of the `header__nav` to modify the rest classes? Say, something like that:

```
.header
   .header__nav .header__nav--active
      .header__icon
         .header__icon-text
      .header__menu
         .header__menu-list
```

It should be obvious to you that I don't want just to manipulate the parent(`.header__nav`), but its children as well, by using CSS only for performance reasons. But in the BEM structure, it seems like I must toggle classes for each of the children elements - this is nonsense! Or I need to use specific state(elem--active) for each of the children elements AND also I need to make sure it's in a proper structure in the CSS order - nonsense once again!

I really hope I didn't get this right and there actually is a way of doing this in performance wise manner - using JS to toggle ONE class to modify the rest with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use nested selectors for that. See https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#nested-selectors for more info.

Comment: Much appreciate it pal!